# Make LinearLayout clickable - Colorize background like the default for ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-linearlayout

Hello my name is Fabian and at the moment I try to programming an Android App.
I have a ListView with some items and above this ListView I added a LinearLayout, which I want to make clickable, to add items to the ListView.
If I touch one entry in the ListView the item gets colorized with the default color, a light grey. I like to have this behaviour for my LinearLayout, too.
I know how to get the LinearLayout clickable.
I did this by

```
android:clickable="true"
android:onClick="addProject"
```

Also I know how to define the backgroundcolor, but I don't know how I can pass the default colors from android of the ListView (android:listSelector) to the LinearLayout.

I tested to define

```
android:background="?android:attr/listChoiceBackgroundIndicator"
```

but in that case the LinearLayout gets colorized blue and only if I touch it, it gets the right color.

I hope you can help me, to pass the default color of a ListView to a LinearLayout.

Comment: Maybe I have to create an extra file with 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable=""/>  <!--pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable=""/> <!-- focused -->
<item android:drawable=""/> <!-- default -->
</selector> But which values I have to define for the drawables, to get the default colors like in the ListView?

Answer (score 1):

Remove below line from your LinearLayout

```
android:onClick="addProject"
```

and add an id to a LinearLayout,

```
android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
```

From JAVA add this,

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v) {
         Toast.makeText(this, "Layout Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think this fixes my problem with the default color I like to have. The onclick-listener already works.